# PlotLegends to show sum's $n$ unevaluated as $n$

Tags: plotting, manipulate, display

I'd like to show the cosine Taylor series. However, I'd like to to see things like `(2n)!` evaluated, but instead `(2*4)!` (e.g. if `n=4`).

This is what I got:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[
    {Cos[x], Sum[(-1)^n x^(2 n)/(2 n)!, {n, 0, t}]},
    {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi},
    PlotLegends -> {
      Cos[x],
      Sum[(-1)^n x^(2 n)/(2 n)!], {n, 0, t}]
    },
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-2, 2}},
    Ticks -> {Range[-4 Pi, 4 Pi, Pi/2], Automatic},
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}
  ],
  {t, 0, 16, 1}
]
```

However, it's evaluating `n` in the denominator, which makes numbers quickly quite high and not helpful to understand the series in its whole.

I was trying different things, such as `Unevaluated[...]` but it just ended up me displaying that string `Unevaluated[` and `]`, too. What is the right way to achieve my goal then?

P.S.: I'm a beginner to Mathematica. I just know the basics.

Comment: What does "I'd like to to see things like `(2n)!` evaluated, but instead `(2*4)!`" mean?

Comment: I agree with @Kuba, you may try `Inactivate[Sum[(-1)^n x^(2 n)/(2 n)!, {n, 0, t}], Factorial]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fleshed out version of @egwenesedai's suggestion:

```
Manipulate[
    Plot[
        {Cos[x],Sum[(-1)^n x^(2 n)/(2 n)!,{n,0,t}]},
        {x,-4 Pi,4 Pi},
        PlotLegends->{
            Cos[x],
            StandardForm@Inactivate[1+Sum[(-1)^n x^(2 n)/(2n)!,{n,1,t}],Factorial]
        },
        PlotRange->{Automatic,{-2,2}},
        Ticks->{Range[-4 Pi,4 Pi,Pi/2],Automatic},
        AxesLabel->{"x","y"}
    ],
    {t,0,16,1}
]
```

I use `1 + Sum[.., {n, 1, t}]` instead of `Sum[.., {n, 0, t}]` to avoid an unevaluated `0!`, and I use [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm) so that the terms are ordered in ascending powers of `x` instead of the reverse.

Here is an image showing an example with the desired legend:

[image]

### Add

A minimal improvement avoiding the horizontal enlargement when the expansion increases (more readable in vertical), and to show the correct mathematical series expansion:

```
Manipulate[Labeled[Plot[{Cos[x], 
Sum[(-1)^n x^(2 n)/(2 n)!, {n, 0, t}]}, {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, 
PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-2, 2}}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, 
Ticks -> {Range[-4 Pi, 4 Pi, Pi/2], Automatic}, 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ImageSize -> Medium], 
TraditionalForm@
Grid[{{Red, "f(x)= " Cos[x]}, {Green, 
  "f(x)\[TildeEqual] " HoldForm[
     Sum[(-1)^n x^(2 n)/(2 n)!, {n, 0, k}]] == 
   StandardForm@
    Inactivate[1 + Sum[(-1)^n x^(2 n)/(2 n)!, {n, 1, t}], 
     Factorial]}}, ItemSize -> {{3, 12}, {1, Automatic}}, 
Spacings -> {0, 1}, 
Alignment -> {{Center, Left}, {Center, Left}}]],
{{t, 0, "k"}, 0, 16, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
ContinuousAction -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way (although Carl suggestion looks better):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{Cos[x], Sum[(-1)^n x^(2 n)/(2 n)!, {n, 0, t}]}, {x, -4 Pi, 
   4 Pi}, PlotLegends -> {Cos[x], 
    With[{t = t}, Defer@Sum[(-1)^n x^(2 n)/(2 n)!, {n, 0, t}]]},
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-2, 2}},
  Ticks -> {Range[-4 Pi, 4 Pi, Pi/2], Automatic},
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}
  ], {t, 0, 16, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another way, which seems to me to be closer to what you asked for than the answers that proceeded this post.

```
Manipulate[
  Column @
    {Plot[{Cos[x], Sum[(-1)^n x^(2 n)/(2 n)!, {n, 0, t}]}, {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi},
      PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-2, 2}},
      Ticks -> {Range[-4 Pi, 4 Pi, Pi/2], Automatic},
      AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
      AspectRatio -> 1/4,
      ImageSize -> 500],
    LineLegend[{ColorData[97][1]}, {Cos[x]}],
    LineLegend[
      {ColorData[97][2]}, 
      {Sum[(-1)^n x^(2 n)/With[{n = n}, HoldForm[(2 n)!]], {n, 0, t}]}]},
  {t, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]